# tesseract ocr: why a png image containing computer digits returns me garbage when I ocr it to a text file?

Tags: png, ocr, tesseract-ocr

I've installed tesseract ocr `5.3.0` (on Debian 12)

I want to scan and ocr this png file:

[image]

When I execute a:

```bash
tesseract cp1.png cp1
```

the output `cp1.txt` contains unexpected garbage:

```
y seeseeggegegegenagesseagegs

feésidaedsdcsdasaredadacd

sgsessesesssesagess

B isgsddsadsdecansas

geverdcdessaguce sses

SERRRERRRRSRSRSERRRERSEsesR
an
```

Why?

Comment: Picture's too small & fuzzy. Readiris can't read it either… though it does a slightly better job, some of it [maybe half] comes out as actual numbers, though not necessarily the right ones.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks! I tried another  one of better quality and it worked better.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I had no clue, it was my very first ocr. I didn't figured the image itself could be too bad

Comment: @MarcLeBihan, sorry, I wasn't criticizing your effort! The image with which you're working was causing the issue, and I wrote an answer on how an image can be improved for OCR, if one has no control of the source.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the image needs to be better.  There is no other answer required.

Comment: @RohitGupta I recommend to keep it open, because first users of tesseract ocr, like me, will know that an output of garbage characters only is the sign of an image of quality too low, for input. That the answer. The good answer to a question of a problem that might happen to tesseract ocr users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCR depends on clear images. If details are a bit unclear to a human reader, OCR would have even more difficulty discerning characters.

Ideally, when *scanning* or *photographing* text, the image should be optimized so that there is clear contrast between text and background. Wrinkles and folds should be minimized, e.g., by perpendicular lighting in photography, or moderate pressure in scanning. If there are colored stains, images can be adjusted to remove blotches of that color.

Images can be also improved, afterwards, for use in OCR. About three minutes were spent using free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) to produce the image below from that in the question. It was processed "by inspection" to decrease gamma, increase contrast, and increase sharpness, but this processing could be improved by *testing* with the OCR tool to optimize accuracy.

[image: Processed image]

In addition, if one is using *Tesseract* extensively on similar data, it is possible to [train](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html) the tool to recognize specific fonts and specific characters. If one is dealing *just* with numerical data, for example, *Tesseract* can be trained to recognize *only* digits, punctuation and spaces, increasing accuracy. That training takes some effort, and might be worthwhile only for a long-term project with voluminous data (e.g., digitizing many back-issues of a newspaper that used only a few fonts).